# Why is Close-ChannelFutureListener not notified?

Tags: http-headers, netty

I have implemented a HTTP-Server in Netty using its built-in functionality. Now i implemented support for Range-Headers which allow to receive only part of a page. What i do in netty is:

```
final RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile( file, "r" );
raf.seek( ranges[ 0 ] );

HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse( HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT );
// MUST include accept-ranges!!
response.setHeader( HttpHeaders.Names.ACCEPT_RANGES, "bytes" );
// MUST include content-range
response.setHeader( HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_RANGE , "bytes " + ranges[ 0 ] + "-" + ranges[ 1 ] + "/" + file.length() );

if ( null != mime )
  response.addHeader( HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, mime.substring( 0, mime.indexOf(' ') ) );
response.setHeader( HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, "" + ( ( ranges[ 1 ] - ranges[ 0 ] ) + 1 ) );

event.getChannel().write( response );

event.getChannel().write( new ChunkedInput() {
   private boolean endOfStream = false;
   private byte[] buffer = new byte[ 4096 ];
   private long bytesRead = ranges[ 0 ];

   @Override
   public boolean hasNextChunk() throws Exception {
     return !this.endOfStream;
   }

   @Override
   public Object nextChunk() throws Exception {
     if ( false == this.endOfStream ) {
       int read = raf.read( this.buffer );
       if ( read == -1 || this.bytesRead >= ranges[ 1 ] ) {
         this.endOfStream = true;
         return new DefaultHttpChunk( ChannelBuffers.EMPTY_BUFFER ); // send isLast 
       }

       if ( this.bytesRead + read > ranges[ 1 ] ) {
         read = ( int ) ( ranges[ 1 ] - this.bytesRead ) + 1;
         this.bytesRead = ranges[ 1 ]; // next iteration will send last chunk
       }

       this.bytesRead += read;

       return new DefaultHttpChunk( ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer( this.buffer, 0, read ) );
     }

    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEndOfInput() throws Exception {
    return this.endOfStream;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws Exception {
    raf.close();
  }
} ).addListener( ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE );
```

The problem is that the ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE will never be called. I tried also my own implementation for the listener - it won't get called. I don't think that my ChunkedInput-Implementation is the problem, i'm using the same principle in different parts of the server. When the stream is finished it returns ChannelBuffers.EMPTY_BUFFER and then close will be called from netty, so the stream is definitely finished.
I managed to workaround the problem doing a channel.close() after raf.close in the close-method but this hack doesn't make me happy. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The FutureListener will get notified once isEndOfInput() returns true. So I think you should debug if isEndOfInput() will ever be true in this case.

Comment: The problem was not that isEndOfInput has to return true, this was always the case when the end of my stream was reached. The real problem was that nextChunk didn't return NULL when isEndOfInput returned true, in my case it returned the last chunk. Netty only recognizes the end of a stream when isEndOfInput returns true AND nextChunk returns null.

Comment: if thats the case then its a bug.. Can you please open a bug report at netty's issue tracker. An unit test would be very nice also, or event better a fix ;)

Comment: I added a test case for it and the behavior you seen is not reproducable. Maybe you use an old version of netty ?

Comment: Strange, what I'm doing is the following: an Application-Server (JBOSS 5) connects to another self-written media-server, where both use HTTP-Netty. The MS sends the file using HTTP to the AS and the AS writes it through to the socket of the incoming request in a servlet. With my old implementation the AS never received the isLastChunk, but with my changes it does. An interesting note: when redirecting the request directly to the MS it works also with the old implementation.

Comment: thats quite old.. Current is 3.4.6.Final, I guess there was a bug in older versions